# Solving 1st Order Partial Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have the following partial differential equation:

\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_{1}} \left(\frac{2+x_{3}^{2}}{1+x_{3}^{2}}\right) + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_{3}} = 0
\end{equation}

Whose solution is:

\begin{equation}
\phi(x)=x_{1} - x_{3} - \tan^{-1}(x_{3})
\end{equation}

I've been trying, but I can't figure out what steps were followed to arrive to the solution. Unfortunately, I only have experience solving ordinary differential equations and no experience solving partial differential equations.

Can anyone give me an idea? Any help would be appreciated.

PD: The original problem says that it can be solved by separation of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To facilitate writing let $\quad x_1=x$ and $x_3=y$ .
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \left(\frac{2+y^{2}}{1+y^{2}}\right) + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = 0
\end{equation}
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{\left(\frac{2+y^{2}}{1+y^{2}}\right)}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{d\phi}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{\left(\frac{2+y^{2}}{1+y^{2}}\right)}=\frac{dy}{1}\quad\implies\quad \int \frac{2+y^{2}}{1+y^{2}}dy=x$+constant.
$$y-x+\tan^{-1}(y)=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $d\phi=0$ :
$$\phi=c_2$$
This was obvious since $\phi=$constant is obviously a trivial solution of the PDE.

The general solution of the PDE on form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\boxed{\phi(x,y)=F\big(y-x+\tan^{-1}(y)\big)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function until some valid boundary condition be specified.

CONDITION :

If the condition is $$\phi(0,0)=0,$$
then $0=F\big(0-0+\tan^{-1}(0)\big)$
$$F(0)=0$$
They are infinity many functions which are equal to zero when the argument is zero.

Thus the PDE with condition $\phi(0,0)=0$ as infinity many solutions.

The specified condition $\phi(0,0)=0$ is not sufficient to determine a unique solution. This is consistent with the judicious comment from HK Tan.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that we can write this as

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1}\left( 1+ \frac{1}{1+x_3^2}\right) + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_3} = 0.$$

We shall solve this by the method of characteristics (this is a common method to solve PDE, especially first-order PDEs).

Let $\phi(x_1,x_3) = \phi(x_1(x_3),x_3))$

(ie look at a curve with parameter $x_3$ to parameterize $x_1$)

Then, we have

$$\frac{d}{d x_3} \phi(x_1(x_3),x_3)) = \frac{d x_1}{d x_3} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_3}$$

which the above is equals to $0$ by the PDE if we set
$$ \frac{d x_1}{d x_3} =  1+ \frac{1}{1+x_3^2}.$$

One can solve this ODE to obtain (note here that $x_1(0)$ is a constant, it refers to the value of $x_1$ at $x_3 = 0$)

$$x_1(s) = x_3 + \tan^{-1}(x_3) + x_1(0).$$

Rearranging, we have

$$x_1(0) = x_1 - x_3 - \tan^{-1}(x_3).$$

From our above computation, $\frac{d}{d x_3} \phi = 0$, so $\phi$ is constant along this curve $x_1(x_3)$. This implies that

$$\phi(x_1(x_3),x_3) = \phi(x_1(0),0) = f(x_1(0)) = f(x_1 - x_3 - \tan^{-1}(x_3)) $$

if the auxiliary condition $\phi(x_1,0) = f(x_1)$ is imposed. Thus, the solution should depend on the boundary condition at $x_3 = 0$ (for example). In general, the solution is thus given by

$$\phi(x_1(x_3),x_3) = f(x_1 - x_3 - \tan^{-1}(x_3)) $$

for arbitrary functions $f$. This is of the right form that you have mentioned above, but to determine the exact solution, I would require a boundary condition.

Comment: The boundary condition is $\phi(0,0)=(0,0)$.

Comment: That still does not make sense; for boundary conditions in PDE, you are required to have an arbitrary variable in it; say $\phi(x,0) = x$, or $\phi(0,y) = y^2$, or even $\phi(x,x) = x^3$! (Please do not just edit your comment since I will not be notified of any changes and would not be able to respond directly)